# Using a Poker Hand Evaluator for Ranking Horse Race Results

Tags: algorithm, sorting, poker

Can I use any of the popular Poker Hand Evaluation programs to Rank Predictions of Horse Race Outcomes?

A Contest requires players to Rank the Probable Finish Order of X number of Horses in a Horse Race.

Because there will usually be no more than 13 horses, I am thinking that maybe a Poker Hand Evaluator could be used to rank all the players on who came closest to having the Perfect Prediction with X horses all in the Correct Finish Position.

So, I would need to specify the Correct Ranking of the Horses, and make the 1st Place horse the Ace, 2nd place the King, 3rd place the Queen, 4th place the Jack and so on.

Then I would need a way to enter each player's "Hand" or Predicted Ranking Outcome.

Then I would need to compare each player's "Hand" with the Rankings in the Table.

Then I would need to receive a Ranking for each Player from the program, which I can then turn into a Leaderboard.

Once I get the Ranking Position from that Last Step, I have other code which will generate the Leaderboard...

It is how to get that Ranking Position for each player which is stumping me.
I need to know whether I could adapt any of the published Poker Evaluators for my purposes, or whether I have to hire a coder to start from scratch.

Comment: The horse race result predictions and the poker hand evaluator seem like very different things to me; I can't imagine how you'd use one for the other. A poker hand evaluator looks for specific unordered combinations (pair, straight, flush...) whereas the race result evaluator would need to look at how much the order of one hand differs from another.

Comment: Correct, except that the poker evaluator must rank hands which are simply A-High, or 10 high, and then see who has the highest sequence -which is essentially the same thing as for a horse race.  23578 beats a 23678.